# How to check name of Django url in view

Tags: python, django, django-urls

say this is my url:

```
url(r'^$', mainApp_views.homepage),
```

Is it possible to check this text = "mainApp_views.homepage" in view and middleware ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like

```
from django.urls import resolve


def your_view(request):
    # resolve the url from the path
    url_name = resolve(request.path).url_name
```

You will probably want to add names to your urls too `name='home'`

Comment: @python_beg2 lol not quite =) I had the same problem myself at one point =D

Comment: I think this should be `from django.urls import resolve` nowadays.

Comment: @TreyPiepmeier Possibly but this was 1.10/1.11 but thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

As of Django 2.0, you need to import `resolve` from `django.urls`:

```
from django.urls import resolve

def your_view(request):
    url_name = resolve(request.path).url_name
    print(url_name) #prints the "name" attribute in your urlpatterns
```